# CADD conversion to shapefile, unable to open

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, convert, autocad, cad

I received a shapefile (which was not zipped and maybe that is the issue it came in the email as just a .shp etc.) which I threw into a folder.

This data was a CADD file not sure if it was Microstation or Autodesk, but it had been converted to a shapefile and needed a projection assigned to it. I did that and I still cannot zoom to the layer.

I think it may have to do something with the "Extent", the numbers go to infinity basically.

Maybe I missed something or need to do something else to make this work, I work in NAD 83 StatePlane Cal V FIPS 0405 projections.

I have two images below regarding the topics in the body of this text.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A shapefile is a shapefile if is has at least 3 file suffixes (`.shp`,`.shx`,`.dbf`) and it should have a `.prj` as well.

Comment: Great, thank you for your insight.

Comment: Sometimes CAD data isn't georeferenced to a 'known' pcs and/or has units or a scale applied that can give really large numbers like that. Try going back to the provider and asking for more information.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you very much, this is the direction I had headed towards and your comment makes me feel good that it was the right decision.